# I cannot execute SDK in my html code

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm very new to facebook development and SDK, and I'm making a website for my business, and I stuck this code:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{your-app-id}',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

into the html code immediatly after opening the body for my unpublished website, and somehow, I cannot run any facebook applications, like the like button, and the share button, after I inserted them into my code inside of certain divs which I made for the facebook buttons. I copied and pasted the code immediatly from the facebook development pages, yet the fb buttons don't load after I run the code. 
What am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any errors? create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I saw elsewhere to get rid of the {} around the id, yet it still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, you need to replace `{your-app-id}` with your app id, e.g `appId : '123457898'`

Comment: I did that, and it still didn't execute. I have a table in the body, and in the second <th>, I placed a like button, which didn't load, when I loaded the html

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your problem or at least post the link where it doesn't work?